# static environment object build dependant transcode from swift to kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In iOS I am using a struct with only static elements to group all environment datas together such as constants and globals (its much more readable in code that way and it allows to have some hierarch in it).

Some of these datas are dependant on the build being PROD(action), DEV(elopement) and ACC(eptance); I solve this by having different targets in xCode and using a specific extension file that is only included for the matching PROD, DEV and ACC target.This works extremely nice in xCode/iOS/Swift:

```
//defines environment variables and functions that are not dependant on the dev, prod and acc builds of the app

struct Environment {

    //defines constants that are independant of the environment
    struct Constants {
        static let unInitializedId          = "unInitializedId"
        static let userLanguageKey          = "userlanguage"
        struct IAP {
            static let prodId_PackagePrefix     = "com.example.packprefix"
            static let prodId_Package_Custom    = "com.example.custom"
            static let prodId_Package_Favorites = "com.example.fav"
        }
    }
    //different storyboards used in the app
    struct StoryBoard {
        static let main       = "main"
        static let exercises  = "exercises"
        static let trainings  = "trainings"
        static let packages   = "packages"
        static let videos     = "videos"
        static let common     = "common"
        static let alerts     = "alerts"
    }

    static let downloadManager = DownloadManager(diskCacheFolder: "cache_downloadmanager")
    static let remoteConfig    = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
}


//defines environment stuff special for PROD builds
//this is included in a seperate file (only included to build for PROD builds)
extension Environment {

    static let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()

    struct Constants {
        static let appId = 1010123
    }

    static func start() {
        //...some prod environment init code here
    }
}


func howItsUsed() {
    //initialize the build dependant environment
    Environment.start()
    //get build independant constant and obj out of the environment
    let buildIndependant_var = Environment.Constants.unInitializedId
    let buildIndependant_iap = Environment.Constants.IAP.prodId_PackagePrefix
    let buildIndependant_obj = Environment.downloadManager
    //get build specific constant &object
    let buildspecific_var = Environment.Constants.appId
    let buildspecific_obj = Environment.remoteConfig
}
```

In Android I have setup the same system using flavours; I have a DEV, PROD and ACC flavour and this I can also include the same principle of having Environment.kt file that are only compiled for specific flavours.

However, I can't find the equivalent solution for the Swift static structs in Kotlin, certainly not in combination with the extensions.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
sealed class Environment {

    companion object {
        const val name: String = "development"

        fun start() {
           //...some prod environment init code here
        }
    }
}
```

How can I implement these constant hierarch and global statics inside Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

After trying different options I finally decided on the following implementation:

```
open class RootEnvironment {

    open class Constants {
        val maxBreak = 147
        val unInitializedId = "unInitializedId"
        val userLanguageKey = "userlanguage"
        val demoUserName = "John Smith"

        open class IAP {
            val prodId_PackagePrefix = "net.sample.com"
            val prodId_Package_Custom = "net.sample.com"
        }

    }

    open fun start() {
        Log.debug("Starting root environment")
    }

}

object Environment : RootEnvironment() {

    const val name: String = "development"

    object WebService {
        val url = "https://xxxxx"
    }

    object Constants : RootEnvironment.Constants() {
        val maxScreenshotsBeforeBuggingUser = 3

        object IAP : RootEnvironment.Constants.IAP()
    }

    override fun start() {
        super.start()
        Log.debug("Starting Environment <$name>")
    }
}

fun testEnvironment() {
    //call genaral constants
    Log.debug("maxBreak......................... ${Environment.Constants.maxBreak}")
    Log.debug("IAP.prodId_PackagePrefix......... ${Environment.Constants.IAP.prodId_PackagePrefix}")
    //environment specific
    Log.debug("name..............................${Environment.name}")
    Log.debug("maxScreenshotsBeforeBuggingUser...${Environment.Constants.maxScreenshotsBeforeBuggingUser}")
}
```